# Reverse Geocoding: Error using python Geopy for Reverse Geocoding

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I tried using reverse geocoding for some coordinates (longitude and latitude) with python, which is a column of my dataset. I tried using a row of the coordinate system as an example, kept on having an error.

This is my code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import geopy
from functools import partial
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter
import tqdm
from tqdm._tqdm_notebook import tqdm_notebook

# specifying the geocoding service
locator = Nominatim(user_agent="myGeocoder", timeout=30)

cordinates = "-29.4277,26.8160"
location = RateLimiter(locator.reverse(cordinates), min_delay_seconds=1)
location.address
```

And i got this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    158             conn = connection.create_connection(
--> 159                 (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
    160 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     56 
---> 57     for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
     58         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/socket.py in getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    751     addrlist = []
--> 752     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    753         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    342         try:
--> 343             self._validate_conn(conn)
    344         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
    838         if not getattr(conn, 'sock', None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
--> 839             conn.connect()
    840 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py in connect(self)
    300         # Add certificate verification
--> 301         conn = self._new_conn()
    302         hostname = self.host

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    167             raise NewConnectionError(
--> 168                 self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
    169 

NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fb7d6f15490>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


GeocoderUnavailable: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /reverse?lat=-29.4277&lon=26.816&format=json&accept-language=es&addressdetails=1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fb7d6f15490>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))
```

please, what could be the problem??

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem goes with me using an online server for it. Tried it with my system installed jupyter  notebook, and i didn't encounter any problem.